# Session не подхватывается. Требуется повторная авторизация

Tags: c#, telegram, wtelegram

Задача: необходимо авторизоваться по сессии после перезапуска приложения.

Код, который запускается при старте приложения:

```
private readonly string _sessionPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "tg.session");
private Client? _client;

private void TryRecreateSession()
{
    try
    {
        _client = new Client(Config);

        string? Config(string what) => what switch
        {
            "api_id" => _apiModel.ApiId,
            "api_hash" => _apiModel.ApiHash,
            "session_pathname" => _sessionPath,
            _ => null,
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _client = default;
    }
}
```

Код, который происходит во время авторизации:

```
public ICommand PhoneCommand => _phoneCommand ??= new AsyncRelayCommand(async obj =>
{
    try
    {
        await _client.LoginUserIfNeeded();
    }
    catch (WTException)
    {
        if (_client.User is not null)
            await _client.Auth_LogOut();

        await Login(obj, Phone);
    }
});

private async Task Login(object obj, string data)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data))
        throw new ArgumentException($"Попытка передачи пустого значения");

    var response = await _client.Login(data);
    if (response is null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Успешная авторизация");
        return;
    }
    switch (response)
    {
        case "verification_code":
            NeedCode = true;
            break;
        case "password":
            NeedPassword = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

После авторизации успешно создаётся файл `tg.session`, но после перезапуска он не подхватывается - требуется повторная авторизация

Comment: Мне кажется на этот вопрос можете ответить только вы самостоятельно, произведя отладку, пройдясь шаг за шагом по проекту и определив где не то, что вы ожидаете.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вчера часа 4 пытался её найти, но так и не удалось. Сравнивал и пути до session, и метод авторизации (- ничего. Конечно, сегодня после работы попробую ещё, но был-бы крайне благодарен, если-бы мои мучения смогли облегчить

Comment: Удаление строки с командой client.Auth_LogOut() ничего не изменяет

Comment: @EvgeniyZ К сожалению, не помогает. При вызове методе `LoginUserIfNeeded` идет запрос из метода Config атрибута phone_number. Если я его там указываю, то происходит отправка сообщения и всё остальное, что происходит во время авторизации

Comment: У вас кастомный код, содержащий много неизвестных нам, сторонним наблюдателям, переменных. У нас нет минимального, самодостаточного примера, который каждый может запустить и тем самым воспроизвести проблему, у нас нет ничего по сути. В связи с этим, еще раз повторю - только вы можете отладить этот код и выявить проблему. Поставьте точку остановке в самом начале вашей логики, и потом тыкайте `F10` и `F11` (если надо зайти в метод), и смотрите через студию все важные свойства, их значения, что они имеют, и так далее. Также отлавливайте запросы, смотрите чего в них нету, и потом думайте почему.